# How to configure Slick 3.0.0 for Postgres DB (either with Hikari or without) Typesafe Play conf

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, slick

I have a test app that works fine with an H2 in-memory database. Now I'm trying to connect it to our real database. I'm either getting an internal Slick exception, or a "No suitable driver" exception, depending on my approach:

Here's my simple test (which, again, seems to work fine in-memory):

```
"The glimple data model classes" should {
    "insert a glimple row in the database" in {
        val db = Database.forConfig("db.edb") // works on db.h2mem1
        val glimples = TableQuery[GPGlimpleModel]

        val insertGlimples = db.run(glimples += GPGlimple(None, None, 1, true, true, 1))

        val count = Await.result(insertGlimples, Duration.Inf)

        println(count)
        count must beEqualTo(1)
        ...
```

If I turn on the connection pool, as noted here:

```
db.edb = {
    driver = org.postgresql.Driver
    url = "jdbc:postgresql://db-server-1.hyrax.com:5444/CI_0"
    user = "xxx" // masked to protect the innocent
    password = "xxx" // masked to protect the innocent
    keepAliveConnection = true
    // connectionPool = disabled
}
```

I end up getting the following exception. In trying to decipher what's going on, I started with a connection pool enabled (as in, "connectionPool = enabled" or just commenting that line out). That led to more problems and a very, very long exception (shown at the end of this post).

The head of that exception is:

> [error] [error] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/zaxxer/hikari/HikariConfig [error]   caused by
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig

And that just makes no sense to me... because again, it works just fine in-memory.

And here's the build.sbt driver line for Postgres:

```
"org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1201-jdbc41",
```

Following is the full exception... I've posted it to github as suggested at the end of the trace:

> [error] [error] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/zaxxer/hikari/HikariConfig [error]   caused by
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig
>   [error] [error] STACKTRACE [error]
>   slick.jdbc.HikariCPJdbcDataSource$.forConfig(JdbcDataSource.scala:141)
>   [error]
>   slick.jdbc.HikariCPJdbcDataSource$.forConfig(JdbcDataSource.scala:135)
>   [error]
>   slick.jdbc.JdbcDataSource$.forConfig(JdbcDataSource.scala:35) [error] 
>   slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseFactoryDef$class.forConfig(JdbcBackend.scala:223)
>   [error]
>   slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$$anon$3.forConfig(JdbcBackend.scala:33) [error]
>   models.TestGlimpleModel$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$64$$anonfun$apply$65.apply(TestGlimpleModel.scala:166)
>   [error]
>   models.TestGlimpleModel$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$64$$anonfun$apply$65.apply(TestGlimpleModel.scala:158)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.matcher.MatchResult$$anon$12$$anonfun$asResult$1.apply(MatchResult.scala:310)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.matcher.MatchResult$$anon$12$$anonfun$asResult$1.apply(MatchResult.scala:310)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.execute.ResultExecution$class.execute(ResultExecution.scala:25)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.execute.ResultExecution$.execute(ResultExecution.scala:120)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.execute.Result$$anon$10.asResult(Result.scala:230) [error] 
>   org.specs2.execute.AsResult$.apply(AsResult.scala:25) [error]
>   org.specs2.matcher.MatchResult$$anon$12.asResult(MatchResult.scala:310)
>   [error]   org.specs2.execute.AsResult$.apply(AsResult.scala:25)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.main.CommandLineAsResult$$anon$1.asResult(CommandLineAsResult.scala:17)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.main.CommandLineAsResult$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(CommandLineAsResult.scala:21)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.main.CommandLineAsResult$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(CommandLineAsResult.scala:21)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.specification.dsl.mutable.ExampleDsl1$BlockExample$$anonfun$$greater$greater$1.apply(ExampleDsl.scala:39)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.specification.dsl.mutable.ExampleDsl1$BlockExample$$anonfun$$greater$greater$1.apply(ExampleDsl.scala:39)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.specification.core.Execution$$anonfun$withEnv$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Execution.scala:120)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.execute.ResultExecution$class.execute(ResultExecution.scala:25)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.execute.ResultExecution$.execute(ResultExecution.scala:120)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.execute.Result$$anon$10.asResult(Result.scala:230) [error] 
>   org.specs2.execute.AsResult$.apply(AsResult.scala:25) [error]
>   org.specs2.specification.core.Execution$$anonfun$withEnv$1.apply(Execution.scala:120)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.specification.core.Execution$$anonfun$withEnv$1.apply(Execution.scala:120)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.specification.core.Execution$$anonfun$execute$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Execution.scala:70)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.specification.core.Execution$$anonfun$execute$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Execution.scala:70)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.specification.core.Execution.setResult(Execution.scala:76)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.specification.core.Execution$$anonfun$execute$2.apply(Execution.scala:70)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.specification.core.Execution$$anonfun$execute$2.apply(Execution.scala:70)
>   [error]   scala.Option.fold(Option.scala:158) [error]
>   org.specs2.specification.core.Execution.execute(Execution.scala:70)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.specification.process.DefaultExecutor$$anonfun$executeFragment$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Executor.scala:132)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.specification.process.DefaultExecutor$$anonfun$executeFragment$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Executor.scala:130)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.specification.core.Fragment.updateExecution(Fragment.scala:44)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.specification.process.DefaultExecutor$$anonfun$executeFragment$1.apply(Executor.scala:130)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.specification.process.DefaultExecutor$$anonfun$executeFragment$1.apply(Executor.scala:129)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.specification.process.DefaultExecutor$$anonfun$sequencedExecution$1.executedFragment$lzycompute$1(Executor.scala:104)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.specification.process.DefaultExecutor$$anonfun$sequencedExecution$1.org$specs2$specification$process$DefaultExecutor$class$$anonfun$$executedFragment$1(Executor.scala:104)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.specification.process.DefaultExecutor$$anonfun$sequencedExecution$1$$anonfun$3.apply(Executor.scala:109)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.specification.process.DefaultExecutor$$anonfun$sequencedExecution$1$$anonfun$3.apply(Executor.scala:109)
>   [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Task$$anonfun$delay$1.apply(Task.scala:272) [error] 
>   scalaz.concurrent.Task$$anonfun$delay$1.apply(Task.scala:272) [error] 
>   scalaz.concurrent.Task$$anonfun$suspend$1$$anonfun$4.apply(Task.scala:280)
>   [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Task$$anonfun$suspend$1$$anonfun$4.apply(Task.scala:280)
>   [error]   scalaz.concurrent.Task$.Try(Task.scala:385) [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Task$$anonfun$suspend$1.apply(Task.scala:280)
>   [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Task$$anonfun$suspend$1.apply(Task.scala:280)
>   [error]   scalaz.concurrent.Future.step(Future.scala:111) [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future.listen(Future.scala:76) [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future$$anon$1$$anonfun$reduceUnordered$2$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Future.scala:310)
>   [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future$$anon$1$$anonfun$reduceUnordered$2$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Future.scala:309)
>   [error]   scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:750)
>   [error]
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1202) [error]
>   scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
>   [error]   scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
>   [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future$$anon$1$$anonfun$reduceUnordered$2.apply(Future.scala:309)
>   [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future$$anon$1$$anonfun$reduceUnordered$2.apply(Future.scala:305)
>   [error]   scalaz.concurrent.Future.listen(Future.scala:80) [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$listen$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Future.scala:80)
>   [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$listen$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Future.scala:80)
>   [error]   scalaz.Free$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Free.scala:52) [error]
>   scalaz.Free$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Free.scala:52) [error]
>   scalaz.Free.resume(Free.scala:73) [error]
>   scalaz.Free.go2$1(Free.scala:118) [error]
>   scalaz.Free.go(Free.scala:122) [error]
>   scalaz.Free.run(Free.scala:172) [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future.listen(Future.scala:77) [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future$$anon$1$$anonfun$reduceUnordered$2$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Future.scala:310)
>   [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future$$anon$1$$anonfun$reduceUnordered$2$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Future.scala:309)
>   [error]   scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:750)
>   [error]
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1202) [error]
>   scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
>   [error]   scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
>   [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future$$anon$1$$anonfun$reduceUnordered$2.apply(Future.scala:309)
>   [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future$$anon$1$$anonfun$reduceUnordered$2.apply(Future.scala:305)
>   [error]   scalaz.concurrent.Future.listen(Future.scala:80) [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$listen$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Future.scala:80)
>   [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$listen$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Future.scala:80)
>   [error]   scalaz.Free$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Free.scala:52) [error]
>   scalaz.Free$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Free.scala:52) [error]
>   scalaz.Free.resume(Free.scala:73) [error]
>   scalaz.Free.go2$1(Free.scala:118) [error]
>   scalaz.Free.go(Free.scala:122) [error]
>   scalaz.Free.run(Free.scala:172) [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future.listen(Future.scala:77) [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future$$anon$1$$anonfun$reduceUnordered$2$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Future.scala:310)
>   [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future$$anon$1$$anonfun$reduceUnordered$2$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Future.scala:309)
>   [error]   scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:750)
>   [error]
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1202) [error]
>   scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
>   [error]   scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
>   [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future$$anon$1$$anonfun$reduceUnordered$2.apply(Future.scala:309)
>   [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future$$anon$1$$anonfun$reduceUnordered$2.apply(Future.scala:305)
>   [error]   scalaz.concurrent.Future.listen(Future.scala:80) [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$listen$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Future.scala:80)
>   [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$listen$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Future.scala:80)
>   [error]   scalaz.Free$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Free.scala:52) [error]
>   scalaz.Free$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Free.scala:52) [error]
>   scalaz.Free.resume(Free.scala:73) [error]
>   scalaz.Free.go2$1(Free.scala:118) [error]
>   scalaz.Free.go(Free.scala:122) [error]
>   scalaz.Free.run(Free.scala:172) [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future.listen(Future.scala:77) [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future$$anon$1$$anonfun$reduceUnordered$2$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Future.scala:310)
>   [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future$$anon$1$$anonfun$reduceUnordered$2$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Future.scala:309)
>   [error]   scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:750)
>   [error]
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1202) [error]
>   scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
>   [error]   scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
>   [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future$$anon$1$$anonfun$reduceUnordered$2.apply(Future.scala:309)
>   [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future$$anon$1$$anonfun$reduceUnordered$2.apply(Future.scala:305)
>   [error]   scalaz.concurrent.Future.listen(Future.scala:80) [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future.runAsync(Future.scala:143) [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future.run(Future.scala:160) [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Task.attemptRun(Task.scala:104) [error]
>   org.specs2.control.ActionT$.fromTask(ActionT.scala:125) [error]
>   org.specs2.control.ActionTSupport$class.fromTask(ActionT.scala:188)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.control.package$Actions$.fromTask(package.scala:29) [error]
>   org.specs2.reporter.Reporter$$anonfun$report$1.apply(Reporter.scala:47)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.reporter.Reporter$$anonfun$report$1.apply(Reporter.scala:37)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.runner.SbtRunner$$anonfun$specificationRun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(SbtRunner.scala:75)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.runner.SbtRunner$$anonfun$specificationRun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(SbtRunner.scala:75)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.control.ActionT$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ActionT.scala:36)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.control.ActionT$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ActionT.scala:36)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.control.StatusT$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(StatusT.scala:20)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.control.StatusT$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(StatusT.scala:19)
>   [error]   scala.Function1$$anonfun$andThen$1.apply(Function1.scala:55)
>   [error]   scalaz.WriterT$$anonfun$flatMapF$1.apply(WriterT.scala:63)
>   [error]   scalaz.WriterT$$anonfun$flatMapF$1.apply(WriterT.scala:62)
>   [error]
>   scalaz.effect.IO$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(IO.scala:62)
>   [error]
>   scalaz.effect.IO$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(IO.scala:61)
>   [error]
>   scalaz.Free$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Free.scala:60)
>   [error]
>   scalaz.Free$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Free.scala:60)
>   [error]   scalaz.Free.resume(Free.scala:72) [error]
>   scalaz.Free.go2$1(Free.scala:118) [error]
>   scalaz.Free.go(Free.scala:122) [error]
>   scalaz.Free.run(Free.scala:172) [error]
>   scalaz.effect.IO$class.unsafePerformIO(IO.scala:22) [error]
>   scalaz.effect.IOFunctions$$anon$6.unsafePerformIO(IO.scala:227)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.runner.SbtRunner$$anonfun$newTask$1$$anon$4.execute(SbtRunner.scala:40)
>   [error]   sbt.ForkMain$Run$2.call(ForkMain.java:294) [error]
>   sbt.ForkMain$Run$2.call(ForkMain.java:284) [error]
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [error]
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   [error]
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   [error]   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [error] [error]
>   CAUSED BY java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig [error]
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372) [error]
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361) [error]
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [error]
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360) [error]
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) [error]
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) [error] 
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) [error]
>   slick.jdbc.HikariCPJdbcDataSource$.forConfig(JdbcDataSource.scala:141)
>   [error]
>   slick.jdbc.HikariCPJdbcDataSource$.forConfig(JdbcDataSource.scala:135)
>   [error]
>   slick.jdbc.JdbcDataSource$.forConfig(JdbcDataSource.scala:35) [error] 
>   slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseFactoryDef$class.forConfig(JdbcBackend.scala:223)
>   [error]
>   slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$$anon$3.forConfig(JdbcBackend.scala:33) [error]
>   models.TestGlimpleModel$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$64$$anonfun$apply$65.apply(TestGlimpleModel.scala:166)
>   [error]
>   models.TestGlimpleModel$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$64$$anonfun$apply$65.apply(TestGlimpleModel.scala:158)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.matcher.MatchResult$$anon$12$$anonfun$asResult$1.apply(MatchResult.scala:310)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.matcher.MatchResult$$anon$12$$anonfun$asResult$1.apply(MatchResult.scala:310)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.execute.ResultExecution$class.execute(ResultExecution.scala:25)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.execute.ResultExecution$.execute(ResultExecution.scala:120)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.execute.Result$$anon$10.asResult(Result.scala:230) [error] 
>   org.specs2.execute.AsResult$.apply(AsResult.scala:25) [error]
>   org.specs2.matcher.MatchResult$$anon$12.asResult(MatchResult.scala:310)
>   [error]   org.specs2.execute.AsResult$.apply(AsResult.scala:25)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.main.CommandLineAsResult$$anon$1.asResult(CommandLineAsResult.scala:17)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.main.CommandLineAsResult$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(CommandLineAsResult.scala:21)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.main.CommandLineAsResult$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(CommandLineAsResult.scala:21)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.specification.dsl.mutable.ExampleDsl1$BlockExample$$anonfun$$greater$greater$1.apply(ExampleDsl.scala:39)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.specification.dsl.mutable.ExampleDsl1$BlockExample$$anonfun$$greater$greater$1.apply(ExampleDsl.scala:39)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.specification.core.Execution$$anonfun$withEnv$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Execution.scala:120)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.execute.ResultExecution$class.execute(ResultExecution.scala:25)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.execute.ResultExecution$.execute(ResultExecution.scala:120)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.execute.Result$$anon$10.asResult(Result.scala:230) [error] 
>   org.specs2.execute.AsResult$.apply(AsResult.scala:25) [error]
>   org.specs2.specification.core.Execution$$anonfun$withEnv$1.apply(Execution.scala:120)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.specification.core.Execution$$anonfun$withEnv$1.apply(Execution.scala:120)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.specification.core.Execution$$anonfun$execute$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Execution.scala:70)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.specification.core.Execution$$anonfun$execute$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Execution.scala:70)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.specification.core.Execution.setResult(Execution.scala:76)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.specification.core.Execution$$anonfun$execute$2.apply(Execution.scala:70)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.specification.core.Execution$$anonfun$execute$2.apply(Execution.scala:70)
>   [error]   scala.Option.fold(Option.scala:158) [error]
>   org.specs2.specification.core.Execution.execute(Execution.scala:70)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.specification.process.DefaultExecutor$$anonfun$executeFragment$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Executor.scala:132)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.specification.process.DefaultExecutor$$anonfun$executeFragment$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Executor.scala:130)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.specification.core.Fragment.updateExecution(Fragment.scala:44)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.specification.process.DefaultExecutor$$anonfun$executeFragment$1.apply(Executor.scala:130)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.specification.process.DefaultExecutor$$anonfun$executeFragment$1.apply(Executor.scala:129)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.specification.process.DefaultExecutor$$anonfun$sequencedExecution$1.executedFragment$lzycompute$1(Executor.scala:104)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.specification.process.DefaultExecutor$$anonfun$sequencedExecution$1.org$specs2$specification$process$DefaultExecutor$class$$anonfun$$executedFragment$1(Executor.scala:104)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.specification.process.DefaultExecutor$$anonfun$sequencedExecution$1$$anonfun$3.apply(Executor.scala:109)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.specification.process.DefaultExecutor$$anonfun$sequencedExecution$1$$anonfun$3.apply(Executor.scala:109)
>   [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Task$$anonfun$delay$1.apply(Task.scala:272) [error] 
>   scalaz.concurrent.Task$$anonfun$delay$1.apply(Task.scala:272) [error] 
>   scalaz.concurrent.Task$$anonfun$suspend$1$$anonfun$4.apply(Task.scala:280)
>   [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Task$$anonfun$suspend$1$$anonfun$4.apply(Task.scala:280)
>   [error]   scalaz.concurrent.Task$.Try(Task.scala:385) [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Task$$anonfun$suspend$1.apply(Task.scala:280)
>   [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Task$$anonfun$suspend$1.apply(Task.scala:280)
>   [error]   scalaz.concurrent.Future.step(Future.scala:111) [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future.listen(Future.scala:76) [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future$$anon$1$$anonfun$reduceUnordered$2$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Future.scala:310)
>   [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future$$anon$1$$anonfun$reduceUnordered$2$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Future.scala:309)
>   [error]   scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:750)
>   [error]
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1202) [error]
>   scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
>   [error]   scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
>   [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future$$anon$1$$anonfun$reduceUnordered$2.apply(Future.scala:309)
>   [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future$$anon$1$$anonfun$reduceUnordered$2.apply(Future.scala:305)
>   [error]   scalaz.concurrent.Future.listen(Future.scala:80) [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$listen$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Future.scala:80)
>   [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$listen$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Future.scala:80)
>   [error]   scalaz.Free$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Free.scala:52) [error]
>   scalaz.Free$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Free.scala:52) [error]
>   scalaz.Free.resume(Free.scala:73) [error]
>   scalaz.Free.go2$1(Free.scala:118) [error]
>   scalaz.Free.go(Free.scala:122) [error]
>   scalaz.Free.run(Free.scala:172) [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future.listen(Future.scala:77) [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future$$anon$1$$anonfun$reduceUnordered$2$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Future.scala:310)
>   [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future$$anon$1$$anonfun$reduceUnordered$2$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Future.scala:309)
>   [error]   scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:750)
>   [error]
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1202) [error]
>   scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
>   [error]   scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
>   [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future$$anon$1$$anonfun$reduceUnordered$2.apply(Future.scala:309)
>   [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future$$anon$1$$anonfun$reduceUnordered$2.apply(Future.scala:305)
>   [error]   scalaz.concurrent.Future.listen(Future.scala:80) [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$listen$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Future.scala:80)
>   [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$listen$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Future.scala:80)
>   [error]   scalaz.Free$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Free.scala:52) [error]
>   scalaz.Free$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Free.scala:52) [error]
>   scalaz.Free.resume(Free.scala:73) [error]
>   scalaz.Free.go2$1(Free.scala:118) [error]
>   scalaz.Free.go(Free.scala:122) [error]
>   scalaz.Free.run(Free.scala:172) [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future.listen(Future.scala:77) [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future$$anon$1$$anonfun$reduceUnordered$2$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Future.scala:310)
>   [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future$$anon$1$$anonfun$reduceUnordered$2$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Future.scala:309)
>   [error]   scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:750)
>   [error]
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1202) [error]
>   scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
>   [error]   scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
>   [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future$$anon$1$$anonfun$reduceUnordered$2.apply(Future.scala:309)
>   [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future$$anon$1$$anonfun$reduceUnordered$2.apply(Future.scala:305)
>   [error]   scalaz.concurrent.Future.listen(Future.scala:80) [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$listen$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Future.scala:80)
>   [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$listen$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Future.scala:80)
>   [error]   scalaz.Free$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Free.scala:52) [error]
>   scalaz.Free$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Free.scala:52) [error]
>   scalaz.Free.resume(Free.scala:73) [error]
>   scalaz.Free.go2$1(Free.scala:118) [error]
>   scalaz.Free.go(Free.scala:122) [error]
>   scalaz.Free.run(Free.scala:172) [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future.listen(Future.scala:77) [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future$$anon$1$$anonfun$reduceUnordered$2$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Future.scala:310)
>   [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future$$anon$1$$anonfun$reduceUnordered$2$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Future.scala:309)
>   [error]   scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:750)
>   [error]
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1202) [error]
>   scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
>   [error]   scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
>   [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future$$anon$1$$anonfun$reduceUnordered$2.apply(Future.scala:309)
>   [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future$$anon$1$$anonfun$reduceUnordered$2.apply(Future.scala:305)
>   [error]   scalaz.concurrent.Future.listen(Future.scala:80) [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future.runAsync(Future.scala:143) [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Future.run(Future.scala:160) [error]
>   scalaz.concurrent.Task.attemptRun(Task.scala:104) [error]
>   org.specs2.control.ActionT$.fromTask(ActionT.scala:125) [error]
>   org.specs2.control.ActionTSupport$class.fromTask(ActionT.scala:188)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.control.package$Actions$.fromTask(package.scala:29) [error]
>   org.specs2.reporter.Reporter$$anonfun$report$1.apply(Reporter.scala:47)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.reporter.Reporter$$anonfun$report$1.apply(Reporter.scala:37)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.runner.SbtRunner$$anonfun$specificationRun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(SbtRunner.scala:75)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.runner.SbtRunner$$anonfun$specificationRun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(SbtRunner.scala:75)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.control.ActionT$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ActionT.scala:36)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.control.ActionT$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ActionT.scala:36)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.control.StatusT$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(StatusT.scala:20)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.control.StatusT$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(StatusT.scala:19)
>   [error]   scala.Function1$$anonfun$andThen$1.apply(Function1.scala:55)
>   [error]   scalaz.WriterT$$anonfun$flatMapF$1.apply(WriterT.scala:63)
>   [error]   scalaz.WriterT$$anonfun$flatMapF$1.apply(WriterT.scala:62)
>   [error]
>   scalaz.effect.IO$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(IO.scala:62)
>   [error]
>   scalaz.effect.IO$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(IO.scala:61)
>   [error]
>   scalaz.Free$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Free.scala:60)
>   [error]
>   scalaz.Free$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Free.scala:60)
>   [error]   scalaz.Free.resume(Free.scala:72) [error]
>   scalaz.Free.go2$1(Free.scala:118) [error]
>   scalaz.Free.go(Free.scala:122) [error]
>   scalaz.Free.run(Free.scala:172) [error]
>   scalaz.effect.IO$class.unsafePerformIO(IO.scala:22) [error]
>   scalaz.effect.IOFunctions$$anon$6.unsafePerformIO(IO.scala:227)
>   [error]
>   org.specs2.runner.SbtRunner$$anonfun$newTask$1$$anon$4.execute(SbtRunner.scala:40)
>   [error]   sbt.ForkMain$Run$2.call(ForkMain.java:294) [error]
>   sbt.ForkMain$Run$2.call(ForkMain.java:284) [error]
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [error]
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   [error]
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   [error]   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [error] [error]
>   [error] This looks like a specs2 exception... [error] Please report it
>   with the preceding stacktrace at
>   http://github.com/etorreborre/specs2/issues

Answer (score 6):

One solution with basic user
on application.conf

```
play.modules.enabled += "modules.DatabaseModule"

MyNameIs = {
  database = {
  driver = org.postgresql.Driver
  url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/databasename"
  user = "postgreuser"
  password = ""
  numThreads = 10
  connectionTimeout = 5000
  validationTimeout = 5000
}

dispatcher {
  fork-join-executor {
    parallelism-factor = 2
    parallelism-max = 20
  }
}
```

on dir app you can create database module like this

```
import javax.inject.{Provider, Inject, Singleton}

import com.google.inject.AbstractModule
import com.typesafe.config.Config
import play.api.inject.ApplicationLifecycle
import play.api.{Configuration, Environment}
import slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend

import scala.concurrent.Future

class DatabaseModule(environment: Environment, configuration: Configuration)     
  extends AbstractModule {
override def configure(): Unit = {
  bind(classOf[Config]).toInstance(configuration.underlying)
  bind(classOf[slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.Database]).toProvider(classOf[DatabaseProvider])
  bind(classOf[models.UserDAO]).asEagerSingleton()

  }
}

@Singleton
class DatabaseProvider @Inject() (config: Config, lifecycle: ApplicationLifecycle) extends Provider[slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.Database] {

  private val db = slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.Database.forConfig("MyNameIs.database", config)

  lifecycle.addStopHook { () =>
    Future.successful(db.close())
  }

  override def get(): JdbcBackend.DatabaseDef = db
}
```

On app/models: UserDAO

```
import java.sql.Date
import javax.inject.{Inject, Singleton}

import com.typesafe.config.Config
import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api._
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

case class User(id: Option[Long] = None, name: String, firstname: String,    email: String, password: String, birthday: Option[Date] = None, signDate: Option[Date] = Some(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis)))

@Singleton
class UserDAO @Inject()(config: Config, db: Database) {


  private val users = TableQuery[Users]

  override def delete(ids: Long*): Future[Boolean] = {
    Future.sequence(for (id <- ids) yield {
      db.run(users.filter(_.id === id).delete).map(_ == 1)
    }).map {
      _.find(i => i == false) == None
    }
  }

  def insert(user: User): Future[Unit] = db.run(users += user).map{()}

  override def update(obj: User): Future[Boolean] = ???

  override def create(obj: User): Future[Boolean] = db.run(users += obj).map(_ == 1)

  override def all: Future[Seq[User]] = db.run(users.result)

  private class Users(tag: slick.lifted.Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "user") {


    type S = String
    type D = Date
    type L = Long
    // attribute name in table database
    def id = column[L](ID, O.AutoInc, O.PrimaryKey)

    def name = column[S](NAME)

    def password = column[S](PASSWORD)

    def firstname = column[S](FIRSTNAME)

    def email = column[S](EMAIL)

    def birthday = column[D](BIRTHDAY)

    def signDate = column[D](SIGN_DATE)

    override def * = (id.?, name, firstname, email, password, birthday.?, signDate.?) <> ((User.apply _)
  .tupled, User.unapply _)
  }

}
```

On controllers Application.scala

```
@Singleton
class Application @Inject()(userdao: UserDAO) extends Controller { code }
```

and on route file:

```
# Home page
GET     /                           @controllers.Application.index
```

Answer (score 3):

Working example for me:

application.conf

```
database {
  dataSourceClass = org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
  properties = {
    databaseName = "some_db"
    user = "local"
    password = "local"
  }
  numThreads = 10
}
```

build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.0.0",
  "com.zaxxer" % "HikariCP" % "2.4.1",
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1201-jdbc41",
  // ...
)
```

And then I just call

```
Database.forConfig("database")
```

Using Java 7, Scala 2.11.6 and sbt 0.13.6.

Comment: According to the [HikariCP github](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#initialization), you would import **HikariCP** and not **HikariCP-java6** if you were using java 7 or 8.

Answer (score 0):

My config with `PGSimpleDataSource` and specified connection pool size:

```
myDb = {
  connectionPool = "HikariCP"
  dataSourceClass = org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
  properties = {
    url = "jdbc:postgresql://"${dbHostName}":"${dbPortNumber}"/"${dbName}
    user = "postgres"
    password = "1"
  }
  numThreads = 10
  minConnections = 10
  maxConnections = 50
  queueSize = 1000
}
```